# How to query database in MediaWiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am working on a custom extension/special page for the first time. I am trying to create a simple page that queries the database and display the result on the page. I got the following code that does that:

```
class SpecialBuildRating extends SpecialPage {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct( 'BuildRating' );
}

function execute( $par ) {

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){

        $buildId = $_GET['id'];

        $db = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE );

        $res = $db->select(
            'build_rating',
            array('article_id', 'user_id', 'vote', 'comment', 'date'),
            'article_id = 1485', //BuildId instead of 1485
            __METHOD__,
            array( 'ORDER BY' => 'date ASC' )
        );
    }

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $output = $this->getOutput();
    $this->setHeaders();

    # Get request data from, e.g.
    $param = $request->getText( 'param' );

    # Do stuff
    # ...
    $wikitext = 'Hello world!';
    $output->addWikiText( $wikitext );

    $outP = '<table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>article_id</td>
                    <td>user_id</td>
                    <td>vote</td>
                    <td>comment</td>
                    <td>date</td>
                </tr>
            ';

    if ($res != null) {
        foreach( $res as $row ) {
            $outP .= '<td>' . $row->article_id . '</td><td>' . $row->user_id . '</td><td>' . $row->vote . '</td><td>' . $row->comment . '</td><td>' . $row->date . '</td>';
        }
    }

    $output->addWikiText( $outP );
    }
}
```

How do I pass the `$buildId`to the `WHERE` statement instead of `1485` in a safe way that prevents injection?

Another question that I have that isn't really an issue is the `$output->addWikiText($var);` output call, is there any easier/more effective way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
$res = $db->select(
    'build_rating',
    array('article_id', 'user_id', 'vote', 'comment', 'date'),
    array( 'article_id' => $buildId ),
    __METHOD__,
    array( 'ORDER BY' => 'date ASC' )
);
```

See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_access for details.

As of outputting, use `$output->addHTML()`, however in that case you're responsible yourself for [preventing XSS](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Another point, in MediaWiki it's recommended to use `$this->getRequest()->getInt( 'name', $defaultValue )` instead of accessing request globals directly.

Comment: Alright, so it's safe to just pass the variables inside select call? Also, if I stick with my current `$output->addWikiText($var);` I don't need to worry about injection and XSS?

Comment: Yes, as long as you rely on MW primitives you're fine. But you must escape stuff manually in cases of non-standard usage like `"article_id > $buildId"`.

Comment: addWikiText() processes its input through MW parser which does not permit any non-safe HTML through. Just as if it was added to pages using during editing.